# For Loop for a Specific Data Column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting, analytics

I have a simple data frame on pandas, and there is a Menu Category; I want to make a for loop that takes all the unique values from a column and create subdata sets with the name of the unique variable.

Essentially I want to make a for loop that does this automatically for me based upon unique variables.

`Rolls = df[df.Menu =='Rolls'] Nigiri = df[df.Menu =='Nigiri'] Specials = df[df.Menu =='Special']`

For every unique variable in df.Menu create a variable data set with the name of the unique variable.

If there is a unique variable called Sashimi in df.Menu I want to be able to run the code and type `Sashimi.head()` and have that subdata set ready to use.

Thank you for reading, and thank you for your time.

Comment: `dfs = dict(list(df.groupby('Menu')))` then `dfs['Rolls']` to access the rolls, etc.

Comment: Note that generating variables programmatically is always a bad idea, a dictionary is ideal.